# Right “time” for publishing on multinational/global websites?

Tags: content, internationalization

I have a website on which I publish a daily update.

Its just german, so Germany/Austria/Switzerland which all share the same timezone.

So the system always publishes the daily new content at midnight, which is fine.

But now I plan to go tap into english/spanish/french/italien speaking areas.

I thought about publishing everywhere at midnight, so californians essentially see the content 18 hours before australians do...

Any ideas on that? How do other websites do it?

Or maby is there a method to keep the shifting delay smaller? Because the zones utc -11 and +12 are essentially only 1 hour apart (when it comes to the time of day, not the actual date).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most global sites just use a single time zone, UTC or their local/server time.

Publishing at a specific time for each timezone seems like overkill, unless there's a reason for it. But if someone in Australia wants to read your site, what would stop them from just using the US Pacific version with the more current content?

Comment: thats true, and its also no problem for me if they decide to do so, but i have such a reason. its like a newspaper. you want to read it daily. and have your daily version available on that day whenever you want to read it, thats why it comes early in the morning. it would be absurd to distribute it n the afternoon sometime.... 
the content also isnt exactly the same. it partly overlaps but is reagion specific.

Comment: Not sure the newspaper analogy works - people don't read *online* papers the same, they'll read when they have the time & interest. And if readers do actually follow the site on a daily schedule, publishing at off times doesn't make it any less daily: it's still new until they read it.